# SQL Server 2008 - available worker thread low alert

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008

We had a recent release in which we deployed ~100 Stored Procedures and we started getting **available worker thread low alert** for the past couple days(almost 100% of the threads are being used). Is there a way to debug this further and find root cause for the same? I would really appreciate any insight on this.

Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)

Comment: what is your `Max worker threads` setting set to ? By default it is set to `0` which means use all available threads.

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks for your response. Max Threads Count: 2944

Comment: well set it to `0` zero , which is default and restart your sql server service, 2944 is maybe a very small number for a reasonably busy server. You should not change the default server settings unless you are 101% sure that why you are doing it and whether you will benefit from it or not.

Comment: CHECK the execution plans of the top CPU consuming procs for optimization opportunities.  `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ORDER BY total_worker_time DESC;`.

Comment: @M.Ali I appreciate the suggestion but we are in a situation where we can't have any downtime for a month from now. And trying to find a way to troubleshoot the SP/SPs causing this.

Comment: My friend your SQL Server requires more resources to do the work you asking your it to do, if you do not provided the required resources, I dont know how to plan to fix this issue, A server SQL Server services is pretty instant anyway.

Comment: I would immediately think Code Change. i.e. Bug introduced.  Specifically where you used to have one stored proc call other stored procs in sequence you now have all those sub-children stored procs being called in parallel.   So think about loop or a queue that used to govern your stored proc calls now is calling as fast as it can (not waiting per loop) or has spread out such that many more stored procs are simultaneously being called instead of being called one after the other.  You could clarify your question if this problem only happens during the 100 sp deployment and not during normal ops